# R polynomial expansion error on "unique points" and degree

Tags: r, polynomial

Why I am getting errors in R for "'degree' must be less than number of unique points" in this case?

```
set.seed(0)
# this is fine
dim(poly(runif(1e3),20))
# this will not work
dim(poly(runif(1e3),30))
```

Where we have $1000$ unique data points from uniform distribution, and the degree is only $30$?

I found the answer to be "numerical overflow"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998919/why-is-poly-complaining-about-degree-less-than-number-of-unique-points

But we are using **orthogonal polynomial** but not raw, would that solve the numerical problem (example `kappa(poly(runif(100),20))`)?

Comment: High degree polynomials can have big numerical stability problems as the condition number of the design matrix gets high enough that even double precision floating point numerical error becomes a problem. I'd ask if you really need a degree 20,degree 30 polynomial and/or fit a spline with lower degree polynomials.

Comment: @MatthewGunn but if we use orthogonal polynomial, should the conditional number always be $1.0$? check `kappa(poly(runif(100),20))`

Comment: I think internally R makes the polynomials orthogonal by doing a QR decomposition? And that whole procedure is going to blow up for high degree polynomial input.

Comment: Have a read on my answer at Stack Overflow: [High (or very high) order polynomial regression in R (or alternatives?)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39803144/4891738)

Comment: @ZheyuanLi your SO answer perfectly answered all of my questions!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi +6 for your SO answer. I understand high degree polynomial almost never useful. The reason I had that is I want to do some simulations on overfitting experiments. Your GAM and other suggestions are really helpful.!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think you still can reward to certain answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In R, the poly function generates a polynomial and then does a QR decomposition to make it orthogonal. For high degree polynomial input, you'll get a high condition number for the Vandermode matrix, and when `poly` tries to make the columns orthogonal, it's going to throw an error (because the input looks rank deficient within the limits of double precision floating point).

Consider:

```
x <- poly(runif(100),30,raw=TRUE)
QR <- qr(x)
QR$rank
```

This is basically what's in the source code of poly. QR$rank is going to be far lower than the degree.

Comment: Sounds like it's poor implementation on the package's part.

Comment: @Alex Poor in what sense or by what standard?

Comment: @whuber may be r should not use RAW expansion as intermediate step?